# extract time range from log file using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to extract time range from a logfile by passing shell variables in `awk`. This is how my log file is.

```
2014-11-24 12:58:59.290 1.1.1.1  etc..
2014-11-24 13:58:59.290 2.2.2.2  etc..
2014-11-24 14:58:59.290 3.3.3.3  etc ..
2014-11-24 12:58:59.290 4.4.4.4  etc.. 
2014-11-24 15:58:59.290 4.4.4.4  etc..
```

Suppose I want to extract time range between 12 hours and 13 hours.   Here is the bash script I have written.

```
stime=12
etime=13
date_=2014-11-24

awk 'BEGIN {
          a='$stime';b='$etime';d='$date_'; FS="[: ]"
       }

      { 
  if ( $1 == d && $2 >= a && $2 < b )
      print $1 $2 $3
      }'  logfile.txt
```

My output should look like this.

```
 2014-11-24 12:58:59.290 1.1.1.1  etc..  
 2014-11-24 12:58:59.290 4.4.4.4  etc..
```

I don't see any output nor any errors.
I don't know what's is going wrong. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: ... also, what is `;` doing inside your `FS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
stime=12
etime=13
date=2014-11-24

awk -v a="$stime" -v b="$etime" -v d="$date" -F "[: ]+" '
  { 
  if ( $1 == d && $2+0 >= a && $2+0 < b )
      print $1,$2,$3
  }'  logfile.txt
```

This produces the output:

```
2014-11-24 12 58
2014-11-24 12 58
```

Notes:

1. `FS="[: ];"` causes the field separator to be set to a colon or space followed by a semicolon.  That combination never occurs in the input file.
2. In the original code, the assignment   `d='$date_';` resulted in `d` having the value of `1979`.  That is because, when introduced in awk code, the expression `2014-11-24` is interpreted as a numerical expression requiring subtraction.
3. It is good practice  to transfer shell variables to awk using the `-v` option.  Both the shell and awk can require proper quoting and the `-v` option allows us to deal with these quoting issues one at a time.
4. awk is capable of doing either numeric or alphabetic comparison depending on context.  By adding `+0` in the code, we assure that awk is doing numeric comparison.

Comment: It worked. I have a question. What is that +0 after $2?

Comment: Very good.  The `+0` tells awk to add zero to the value of `$2`.  This forces awk to treat `$2` as a number.

Comment: @SwateshPakhare [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37265896/3030305) shows an example of a case where the `+0` was essential.